# Cannot find emacs startup file

Tags: linux, emacs, debian

Debian. Fresh installation of emacs using `sudo apt-get install emacs`.

I cannot find startup/initialization file for emacs.

Searched:

```
~/.emacs
~/.emacs.d/init.el
~/.emacs.el
```

I have the directory `~/.emacs.d/` though. Its listing:

```
auto-save-list
%backup%~
games
idlwave
url
```

Consulted [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html#Find-Init) source.

Answer (score 3):

Emacs doesn't need a startup file, you create one if you want one.

These days, the recommended location for your own file is `~/.emacs.d/init.el`

One common way to create a skeletal startup file is to `M-x customize` and change some preferences, then save for future sessions.